# Share UiWebView contents with UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to find the code for sharing the `UIWebView` content.
I got this in `@IBAction`:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
  activityItems: [textField.text as NSString],
  applicationActivities: nil)

presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

What I need to make instead of `textField.text`?

Comment: please leave [tag:xcode] alone. It's about Xcode the IDE's issues.

Comment: what do you mean by "What I need to make"?

Comment: For sharing the content/text of the page open in the Webview

Comment: With UIActivityViewController

Comment: Let me rephrase your question: You would like to get the contents, probably texts, from the web page opened in a `UIWebView`, then share by `UIActivityViewController`. Right? It's suggested to share the URL of the `UIWebView` instead (you can replace the `textField.text` with the URL)

Comment: What I need to write for replacing the textField.text with the URL ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the `textField.text` to web view's URL, you can use the following codes:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController (
        activityItems: [(webView.request?.URL.absoluteString)! as NSString],
        applicationActivities: nil
)

presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

where `webView` is a `UIWebView` instance.

p.s. make sure the web view completed loading before you use this code. (hint: use it in `func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView!)` with `UIWebView` delegate)

Comment: Now with the update of the Swift it just need to change one thing :              ' activityItems: [(webView.request?.URL!.absoluteString)! '

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = self.webView.request.URL ? 
self.webView.request.URL : self.request.URL;
    if (url != nil) {
        NSArray *activities = @[[SVWebViewControllerActivitySafari new], [SVWebViewControllerActivityChrome new]];

        if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"file:///"]) {
            UIDocumentInteractionController *dc = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
            [dc presentOptionsMenuFromRect:self.view.bounds inView:self.view animated:YES];
        } else {
            UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title"], url] applicationActivities:activities];

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
            if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1 &&
                UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            {
                UIPopoverPresentationController *ctrl = activityController.popoverPresentationController;
                ctrl.sourceView = self.view;
                ctrl.barButtonItem = sender;
            }
#endif

            [self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

Take a look at [SVWebViewController](https://github.com/TransitApp/SVWebViewController)